# Angular 11 + Angular Universal + AngularFire + Firebase Cloud Functions not working

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire, angular-universal

I've been struggling for days now to get Angular Universal working on Firebase with Angular 11.2.3 and the latest version of AngularFire namely 6.1.4 in a fresh blank project.

The steps I used to create the project and schematics are:

```
ng new rro-ssr --strict --routing=true --style=sass
```

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

```
firebase init
```

- Initialized Firebase Cloud Functions and Firebase Hosting

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

- Clicked Yes, to create a Firebase Cloud Function to redirect the hosting to

If I'm using `ng deploy` and check out the hosting site it works fine, Angular Universal is doing the Server-Side rendering.

But why is there no way to specify the Cloud Functions folder inside Angular? The project I am working on already has Cloud Functions in the default folder called `functions` in the root directory of the Angular application. Also the generated Cloud Functions from the AngularFire SSR builder are using Javascript while our project is using Typescript.

As it is, I cannot define two separate folders for Firebase Cloud Functions, and I don't want the `@angular/fire:deploy` builder to overwrite my existing Cloud Functions.

Furthermore, if I'm trying to deploy the npm scripts made by Angular Universal (parts of the process are described here https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/universal/cloud-functions.md ), it somehow is not executing the rewrite as described in the link.

`firebase.json`

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "rro-ssr",
      "public": "functions\\dist\\rro-ssr\\browser",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*"
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "ssr"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I was using the link in the "Additional Resources" from Fireship: https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/

Cloud Function `functions/src/index.ts`

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Increase readability in Cloud Logging
require("firebase-functions/lib/logger/compat");

const universal = require('../dist/rro-ssr/server/main').app();

exports.ssr = functions
  .region('us-central1')
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
    memory: '256MB'
  })
  .https
  .onRequest(universal);
```

**Problem**: Even if I just copy everything the `@angular/fire:deploy` builder is putting inside the `dist/{project-name}` folder and executing `firebase deploy`, it's not doing the SSR on the hosting site, if I'm building and deploying manually, and not using the AngularFire SSR builder.

The npm script that I'm using in my `package.json`:

```
"deploy": "npm run build:ssr && npm run --prefix functions build:ssr && firebase deploy",
```

The npm script that I'm using in my `functions/package.json`:

```
"build:ssr": "node cp-angular.js && tsc",
```

The copy script `functions/cp-angular.js`:

```js
// copy files from src/dist folder to functions/dist folder in order to serve them via Firebase Cloud Functions

const fs = require('fs-extra');

(async() => {

    const src = '../dist';
    const copy = './dist';

    await fs.remove(copy);
    await fs.copy(src, copy);
    
    // finally remove the original dist folder
    // await fs.remove(src);

})();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I put the code that is not working in this repository (empty app-root):
https://github.com/sanderschnydrig/ssr_manual

Please use `npm run build:ssr` followed by `firebase deploy` in a firebase project of your choice to reproduce. The .firebaserc needs to be updated for this to work.

And the code that is working in this repository:
https://github.com/sanderschnydrig/ssr_angularfire

Please use `ng deploy` to reproduce. Also the .firebaserc needs to be updated as well.

Comment: Can you please share your `angular.json` project to have visibility on your deploy builder?It should reveal if there is anything that may be triggering the "overwrite" of your functions.

Comment: @FaridShumbar thanks for your reply! I uploaded the code to two separate repositories to reproduce the issue. Please check my updated answer at the end.